# Relation between uniform continuity and uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

Is there a relationship between uniform continuity and uniform convergence? For example, suppose $\{f_{n}\}$ is a sequence of functions each of which is uniformly continuous on $[a, b]$. Then does it follow that $f_{n}$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $[a, b]$? (Maybe with some additional conditions?)

Comment: As a small addition to the correct answer below: you get uniform convergence to some $f$ if additionally your sequence is bounded, and uniformly equicontinuous (i.e. the delta in the continuity can be chosen the same for all functions of  your sequence). This is the Arzela-Ascoli theorem.

Answer (score 13):

No, for example each $f_n$ can be equal to a constant $c_n$, but such that the sequence of real numbers $\{c_n\}$ is not convergent. Even if $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise, it's not enough (take $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $[0,1]$).

However, it's true that a uniform limit on $I$ of uniformly continuous functions on $I$ is uniformly continuous on $I$. To see that, use a $3\varepsilon$-argument: take an integer such that the uniform distance between $f$ and $f_n$ is $\leq\varepsilon$, and use uniform continuity of $f_n$ on $I$ to get the result.

There are also cases where the convergence can be uniform, like in the context of Dini's theorem for example.

Comment: If you state your answer like this it sounds like that it is impossible to conclude uniform convergence even under relaxed assumptions. This is not true. See Dini's theorem or my answer to this question https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3781109/579544

Comment: I do not assert that it is impossible to have uniform convergence. The point is simply to answer the question in the opening post in general.